# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Servlet is not able to read InputStream

Tags: java, servlets, applet, communication, socketexception

I am facing below problem. It is related to socket communication error. Here I am migrating code to JBoss server. I knew this error is related to port blocking. I am running this application locally (Remote Desktop). The communication is between Applet and Servlet. When I run this application as Applet, applet runs on one port and servlet is at 8080 port on local. I have change the security policy for the servlet for the socket communication.

I am getting this error from starting. So please let me know if you have some ideas on this. I have not done any firewall changes, as I am able to ping database servers. Error is below. Here applet gets loaded and communication with servlet happens. But it is getting blocked somewhere.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
  at com.sears.adnet.data.access.servlet.HttpMessage.sendPostObject(HttpMessage.java:112)
```

Comment: Are you able to telnet to port 8080 on that server from that client? If not, it is a firewall problem and off-topic, belongs on serverfault.com.

Comment: I am able to ping 8080. My local(Remote desktop) windows firewall is off. I am able to connect to database through simple Servlet program. Here my applet is able to connect to Servlet but giving above error when it gets InputStream.

Comment: Is it client socket problem? Why are you trying to connect servlet?